# time stamp puzzle

Tags: bug, timestamps

At 9:27 AM (EDT) this question

[Is there another way to solve this problem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2934949/is-there-another-way-to-solve-this-problem)

appears on the page https://math.stackexchange.com/questions as having been asked 6 minutes ago. The question itself is tagged as having been asked 13 hours ago, which is about right since I saw it then.

I'm puzzled. I've tagged this as a bug, but maybe it's not.

Comment: At this point that Question has fallen to the fifth page on [that link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions) and shows as 14 hours old.  I suspect that in navigating back and forth in the site you were seeing an unrefreshed copy of the Questions page from the point when the post was new (6 minutes old).  When you click the link you see it in its current state, but many browsers will not refresh the page when you use the "back" button.

Comment: @hardmath Perhaps, though I  am pretty sure I reloaded the page (Firefox) and the time stamp didn't change. In any case this is not a big deal. I reported it just in case it was an instance of problem that might elsewhere really matter.